# How to download an xml layout file from a server and show the view at runtime in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an activity which i need to have dynamic content as its view.
so i thought in downloading dynamic xml layout file from my server and assign it at runtime.

consider the following idea:

```
public class DynamicContentActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        donloadTheXmlFile(new dataListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String data) {
                parseIntoXmlLayout(data, new xmlListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConvertedIntoView(View v) {
                        setContentView(v);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
}
```

is this possible? and how can i achieve this if possible?

Comment: I don't think you can do this.  XML files in your project are "compiled" into a binary format before being included into the APK.  `R.java` class is generated using the information in the XML files - and compiled as part of your project.  If the XML was not part of your project at build time, you won't be able to use it during run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My actual project deals exactly with this. And apply XML-layouts at runtime is not possible ( until now ).
What I get from database, are metadata-records, which define several controls/components. Based on this i then create those , the metadata gives me everything, I need, like control-text, back-and forecolor, even font-type and font-decoration, and also location and size. In my case I even had to create the "carrier" view dynamically, what I then implemented via fragments. In Your case it is much easier, because You already have a carrier ( mainView). You can analyse the XML and its nodes, extract data and apply a runtime created LayoutObject based on the XML-Data ( is almost the same, You only have no binary, but You get data from XML, which can be used to almost 100% inside a LayoutObject. Then You place Your control onto the layout, and then You place the layout on whatever Your mainView is.